# omniauth 0.2.3 invalid_credentials

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I have been using OmniAuth 0.2.3 with Rails 3.0.7 for facebook authentication. I have obtained application ids for localhost and hosting environment separately. When testing in localhost, everything work like a charm. However, when I run my web application on the hosting server, I keep getting the error "invalid_credentials".

My configurations on the hosting server are shown below:

```
Ruby (ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux])
Ruby on Rails (3.0.7)
OmniAuth (0.2.3)
bundler (1.0.2)
```

GemFile

```
gem 'rails', '>= 3.0.6'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'omniauth'
```

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, 'app_id', 'app_secret', {:scope => "email, publish_stream", :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/pki/tls/certs", :ca_file => "/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem"}}}
end
```

error url

```
http://my_url/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials
```

Any advice or suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: it helps if you show us your controller and model code related to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, by the way I'm interested in it.

did you tried to update credentials on facebook's app settings page? if you left "localhost", then that's the reasong for that error.

also, try to regenerate API keys, and try again.

cheers